# Adding the contents of a hashmap during hashmap creation

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

Is there a way to conditionally add the contents of a hashmap to another hashmap during the creation of the hashmap?
E.g. something like:

```
map.putAll(
   a to b,
   b to c,
   if(otherHashMap != null) otherMap else emptyMap()    
)
```

I am not sure how the syntax would be. Ideally if the `otherMaps` is empty I would prefer nothing to be added

)

Answer (score 2):

You may convert `otherHashMap` into an array of `Pair`s and pass them with other pairs using spread operator:

```kotlin
val map = hashMapOf(
    a to b,
    b to c,
    *(otherHashMap?.toList()?.toTypedArray() ?: emptyArray())
)
```

Another option (without extra objects creation)

```kotlin
val map = hashMapOf(a to b, b to c).apply { putAll(otherHashMap ?: emptyMap()) }
```

Comment: The spread operator, how does it work exactly?

Comment: It passes contents of the array into vararg-parameter (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as far as I know, but I don't see why you'd need to since it isn't any shorter than the regular syntax:

```
val map = mutableMapOf(
   a to b,
   b to c,
)
otherHashMap?.let(map::putAll)
```

Comment: Why `::` there?

Comment: see here for the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#functions
it's a shorthand notation for let{map.putAll(it)}

Comment: You seem to have used the wrong brackets? Shouldn't it be `otherHashMap?.let(map::putAll)`? I think that's why @Jim is confused.

Comment: ah yes, fixed it